# Using GitHub with another Bug-tracker?

Tags: git, open-source, translation, github, bug-tracking

I am involved in this project, [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/), and we are currently using GitHub for our development. We all love Git and GitHub and want to keep using it. However, now the project is getting stable and involved, and it's time we started using a more capable bug tracking system than GitHub's simple issue tracker. We also want to start doing GetText based translations.

We are looking at Launchpad which has both a nice bug tracker and translation manager, but we want to keep using GitHub for development. I'm worried that these will not integrate well, and it will make development harder.

Has anyone used GitHub with another bug tracking system and had any success? Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm also interested in this question. I think the question is really about other bugtrackers that actually integrate with GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

We use Lighthouse with GitHub and the integration in both directions is very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Projects use external (to github) bug tracking systems all the time.  Mostly, you just need to document the way to get to the bug tracker well and inform any current community of the change.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use just-any-old bug-tracker is that you can do cool stuff like link bugs to users, releases, and branches in Launchpad. I'm most interested in a way to get that kind of integration with GitHub.

Answer (score -4):

Use Bugzilla. It may not have direct integration, but it's the best bug-tracking software out there IMHO. And you honestly don't need direct integration for something like bug-tracking.