# Is there an issues plugin for github/visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, github, bug-tracking

Is there a plugin that will show my github issues in visual studio?

Would be pretty cool to be able to see all that info inside the IDE

Comment: This is a simple YES NO Answer question... it should be deemed as constructive.

Comment: Now there is an extension developed at GitHub: https://github.com/rprouse/GitHubExtension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any plugin offering a *direct* integration with GitHub bug tracker.
The [Git Extensions](https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions) don't include that feature (and there are one of the advanced plugin to integrate Git - not GitHub, just Git - within Visual Studio).

Maybe another soution would be to get some kind of integration with *another* bug tracking which then would be able to read from/write to the GitHub issue tracker.
This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782619/using-github-with-another-bug-tracker), for instance, mentioned [LightHouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/) (which isn't a good fit in your case, since it is not integrated with Visual Studio).